# Strange casting of function in c++ (void (**)())

Tags: c, pointers, casting, trezor

I was reading the [code of the bitcoin trezor MCU](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-mcu/blob/master/bootloader/bootloader.c#L63) and found this:

```
(*(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4))();
```

By breaking down some things, I tried to analyze what this line meant:

```
(   *(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4)    )      ();
```

I can see that this is a function call with no arguments, due to the `()` at the end, and that the function is whatever

```
*(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4)
```

points to.

I know that `FLASH_APP_START + 4` will resolve into something, so I just need to figure out what is this:

```
*(void (**)())
```

It is resolving to whatever `void (**)()` points to. But what is `void (**)()`? It looks like a casting to a function, maybe. But I'm not sure. Could you give me an example of what is this calling? Why would you need that?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `(void (**)())` is: cast into pointer to pointer to function returning void. Thus, when you dereference it (`*(void(**)())`), it's of type pointer to function returning void, and you can call it. The `(FLASH_APP_START+4)` is a pointer into a function pointer table. If the type of `FLASH_APP_START` is `char*`, then the 2nd function in the list will be invoked, assuming 32 bit pointers. If the type of `FLASH_APP_START` is `void*`, then 5th function in the table would be called.

E.g. this code would invoke `fun2` on a machine with 32 bit pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1() { printf("fun1\n"); }
void fun2() { printf("fun2\n"); }

int main(void) {
  static void (*table[])() = { fun1, fun2 };

  int const FLASH_APP_START = (int)&table;
  (*(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4))();
}
```

If you need help decoding C types, [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) is your friend.

Comment: why did you use typedef? it confuses me, is there a way to use it without typedef? how can you rewrite 'void'? is it allowed?

Comment: @Gatonito A function is an abstraction that can be used to package some code. It doesn't have to return anything, it's just a way of chopping things down to make it easier for humans to digest. Code with huge functions is very hard to comprehend. Neither the compiler nor the machine cares about whether a function returns anything.

Comment: @Gatonito I didn't "rewrite" `void`... The typedef makes the `table` declaration easier to read, that's all. You could define `table` as `void (*table[])() = { ... }` instead, if you like. Either definition means exactly the same.

Comment: why did you turn the pointer into a char? shouldn't I cast it to a function?

Comment: @Gatonito Not into a `char`, but `char*` - there's a difference. The `FLASH_APP_START` *is* already being cast to a function, that was the whole point of your question. The code you linked to in the question makes it appear that `FLASH_APP_START` is an integer. It doesn't really matter what its type is, it all works the same. You could have `int const FLASH_APP_START = (int)&table;`.

Answer (score 0):

First, `void (**)()` is a pointer to a function pointer, with no arguments and void return type.

Second, `(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4)` means cast an address value `FLASH_APP_START + 4` to the pointer in the first step. `FLASH_APP_START` should be a fixed value. It maybe the NAND flash start address, always used in embedded systems as the vector table.

Third, `*(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4)` dereferences the pointer got in the second step. We got a function pointer now.

Finally, `(*(void (**)())(FLASH_APP_START + 4))()` calls the function we got in the third step.

Summary: There is a function entrance address stored at the address `FLASH_APP_START + 4`. We get the function entrance address. cast it to a function pointer, and call it.

Comment: parameter list `()` means unspecified arguments in C. `(void)` would mean no arguments.